# How to set precision for adDecimal parameter to avoid "invalid precision" error?

Tags: c++, sql-server, ado

I have a table on my MSSQL server with a column defined as decimal(8,2).

From my c++ app I define the following parameter to be passed to the sp.

```
pParam1 = pCommand->CreateParameter ( 
_bstr_t ("Thing"),
adDecimal,          
adParamInput,
8,                  
(_variant_t) thing);
pCommand->Parameters->Append (pParam1);
```

I get an error "Invalid precision".

How do I have to define the precision in the pParam1 setup to make it match the definition in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is (18,0). In VBScript it would be:

```
pParam1.Precision = 8
pParam1.NumericScale = 2
```

For C++ it is amazingly similar:

```
pParam1->Precision = 8;
pParam1->NumericScale = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to subsequently set the [Precison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675263%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [NumericScale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675305%28VS.85%29.aspx) properties of the parameter object

Comment: Hi! I found that out to, but from MSDN's pages I do not find/understand the "how", in other words: I can't find the correct syntax.